# Is there a list of Intellij keystrokes that aren't already used?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm looking to a nice shortcut to open an external tool and everything easy seems like it is in use?

Is there a list somewhere of shortcuts reserved for users to add. Maybe just one so that I can use that as the first keystroke and have second keystrokes available to map a wide range of things.

Also if you have one you like to use to open vim let me know.

Comment: I discovered [CTRL+SHIFT+O] is open at least on the xwin default.  I decided to make that at least my first stroke at least for external tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no shortcuts in IntelliJ IDEA which are intentionally reserved for users to use in their own keybindings. I don't think there's any good solution to get the list of shortcuts which are currently unused.